Deployed Web is blank after changing domain using GoDaddy Domain
I am using github pages for deployment, the web worked fine when using github url but when i try to change the domain using the one I bought from go daddy. The web seems to be blank with no error to speak of.
Github Repo: https://github.com/GilbertKrantz/UniPal
Web URL: https://unipal.online/
GoDaddy DNS:


I have tried changing the path, and from the network tab when I inspect it seems to have loaded. It just that the page is blank for some reason.
Update: I have also changed the base in vite.config.js to the url of the website

Your "live" version does not include the <script> tag loading /src/main.jsx

I just checked; I am pretty sure it does, or could you please specify, of what do you mean by "live" version

I mean, when I go to the URL you show above and view the source, that line is not included.

I think about two things here:
First and foremost i cant see on those DNS records you posted which CNAME record could deliver our requests to https://github.com/GilbertKrantz/UniPal apparently you have one of them for the WWW pointing to to gilbertKrantz.github.io which returns a 404. I think you could setup properly GitHub deployment service to manage itself with a custom domain and there use the one you bought.
The other thing is about your react-router approach.
In your  component at /src/main.jsx
since you are trying to deploy your app to a unipal.online domain i assume that you don't need the /UniPal basename , rather than just "/" .This may be causing troubles with your base:"https://unipal.online/" set at your vite.config.js
Setting this two things properly i think it will be pretty straight forward. Like this deploy on Netlify
https://66ba509b367f130baa2078c2--warm-dusk-074575.netlify.app/

Thank you for the suggestion, the 1st suggestion about the cname is what i got from the github documentation. But the 2nd suggestion seems tobe the problem for me. after changing the basename it worked flawlessly. Thank you again.
